# Entity class in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted to know what exactly is entity class in asp.net, what are the applications of it,is their any simple example to understand clearly about entity class in asp.net

Comment: What do you mean by "entity class". Do you mean a model class?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [tutorials on this page](http://www.asp.net/mvc) would provide insight (especially paragraph `5. Models (Data)`).

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework add own model class when you add the database model.

For add more usefull futures for your model (like input validation, view model binding) you can create a additional model classes. Go to Models folder - right mouse click - Add new - Class. Name it (for example MyClass.cs).

For example we have a comments table (with next rows):
commentId (int autoinc), commneterId (int(11)), commentBody(text)

And profile table (we will join 2 tables with Linq to Entities):
userId (int 11 autoinc), Name (varchar 255)

For this example we have created the Entity model (using entity wizard)

Next one we want to craete a view model (MyClass.cs):

```
namespace yourproject.Models
{
    public class MyClass
    {
            public class GetLastComments
            {
                public IQueryable<LastComments> LastCommentsList { get; set; }
            }
            public class LastComments
            {
                public int CommentId{ get; set; } // comment id
                public string CommenterName { get; set; } //commentre name
                public string Comment { get; set; } //commnet body
            }
    }
}
```

And controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
            var model = new MyClass.GetLastComments();
            var getComments = (from m in db.profile
                             join n in db.comments on m.userId equals n.commneterId
                             orderby m.commentId descending
                             select new MyClass.LastComments
                             {
                                 CommentId= n.commentId,
                                 CommenterName = m.Name,
                                 Comment = n.commentBody,
                             }).AsQueryable();
            model.LastCommentsList = getComments;
            return View("Index", model);
    }
```

This is a small example of using Entity Classes (not classes, additional models  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have not tagged Entity Framework, I am assuming that you are talking about Entities within your Model folder/directory that gets created as part of the ASP.NET MVC Template.

The classes that you create in the Model folder/directory are generally the objects that you'd use to save data. In most cases nowadays, you will see a lot of people using ORMs (Object Relational Mappers) that will map those classes to database tables. Which means that your models are clean and free of any direct knowledge of what data store they are using.